# Is DateTime a primitive type?

Tags: c#, primitive, primitive-types

According to what I can find I believe `DateTime` is a primitive type but when I check my `DateTime` variable the property `IsPrimitive` is false.

[7.3 Primitive Types](http://web.archive.org/web/20150513044843/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900(v=vs.71).aspx) (archive.org mirror)

In the article above you'll see that they say `DateTime` is primitive. So is there anything I'm doing wrong or have I read the article wrong?

Comment: "The Date value type is a primitive type, which represents a date and/or a time and **maps to** System.DateTime"

Comment: This article is a *Visual Basic* article.

Comment: `typeof(DateTime).IsPrimitive` returns `false` as well.

Comment: Why do you care? Being primitive or not is completely irrelevant in practice. `DateTime` is simply a value type.

Comment: This question deserves more credit than it has gotten.  It is surprising to not have a direct equivalent of VB.NET's `Date` in C#, and there's no telling how many people have spent at least a brief moment searching for one.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It's not irrelevant. For example determining whether the [FromURI] or [FromBody] attributes will apply the default behavior depends on whether the value is a primitive type or not in an API Method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [MSDN page on IsPrimitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive(v=vs.110).aspx) lists the .net types that are considered as primitive as far as this method is concerned:

> The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32,
>   UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

And DateTime is not in this list.

Answer (score 8):

`Date` (which maps to `System.DateTime`) is a primitive type **of the Visual Basic .NET language** (VB.NET for short).

It's not a primitive type in C#, and it's not a primitive type in the CLR either.

A primitive type for a given language is a type for which you can write a string literal, and this literal is understood by the compiler to be of the relevant type. You can't do this for DateTime in C#.

A primitive type for the CLR is a type on which some low level optimizations are allowed. It's very restricted: only string and the different integer and floating-point numbers structs are primitive types.

Comment: I wouldn't call `decimal` primitive, despite the compiler magic. I would avoid the word "primitive" when talking about C#, since the spec doesn't define it properly. At the CLR level the concept it at least defined, but still of little practical relevance.

Comment: To the CLR, `String` is not primitive in the sense that `typeof(string).IsPrimitive` is false.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I agree! The C# Language Specification mentions ***predefined struct types*** which have a big intersection with the types the CLR considers primitive. Although neither set is included in the other. Of course C# also has keywords for the "predefined" types `string`, `object` and `dynamic`, but they are reference types. Finally, the special type `void` has its own keyword in C#, but C# does not consider it a struct type, apparently, and the CLR does not consider it primitive. `void` is an anomalous value type.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Type.IsPrimitive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine whether a type is a primitive.

For your particular question, you can try `DateTime.Now.GetType().IsPrimitive`.  (This does return `false`). The link in the **accepted answer refers to the Visual Basic language specification primitive types** ...